# Why would a PyDev breakpoint on a return statement only work part of the time?

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, pydev

I have some code that calculates the price of a stock option using Monte Carlo and returns a discounted price.  The final few lines of the relevant method look like this:

```
    if(payoffType == pt.LongCall or payoffType == pt.LongPut):
        discountedPrice=discountedValue
    elif(payoffType == pt.ShortCall or payoffType == pt.ShortPut):
        discountedPrice=(-1.0)*discountedValue
    else: 
        raise Exception
    #endif
    print  "dv:", discountedValue, " px:", discountedPrice
    return discountedPrice
```

At a higher level of the program, I create four pricers, which are passed to instances of a portfolio class that calls the *price()* method on the pricer it has received.

When I set the breakpoint on the *if* statement or the *print* statement, the breakpoints work as expected.  When I set the breakpoint on the *return* statement, the breakpoint is interpreted correctly on the first pass through the pricing code, but then skipped on subsequent passes.

On occasion, if I have set a breakpoint somewhere in the flow of execution between the first pass through the pricing code and the second pass, the breakpoint will be picked up.

I obviously have a workaround, but I'm curious if anyone else has observed this behavior in the PyDev debugger, and if so, **does anyone know the root cause?**

Answer (score 0):

The issues I know of are:

1. If you have a StackOverflowError anywhere in the code, Python will disable the tracing that the debugger uses.
2. I know there are some issues with asynchronous code which could make the debugger break.

A workaround is using a programmatic breakpoint (i.e.: `pydevd.settrace` -- the remote debugger session: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html has more details on it) -- it resets the tracing even if Python broke it in a stack overflow error and will always be hit to (the issue on asynchronous code is that the debugger tries to run with untraced threads, but sometimes it's not able to restore it on some conditions when dealing with asynchronous code).